# Object Detection API using OpenCV but got wrong color output

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I tried to detect a image in tensorflow object detection api.

But matplotlib can not show image successfully so I changed to use opencv to display the image result.

I got my result but the image colour is incorrect:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYQlA.jpg

Am i missing any color handle script?

Original Source:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

I changed last 2 scripts:

```
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
    output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np,
        output_dict['detection_boxes'],
        output_dict['detection_classes'],
        output_dict['detection_scores'],
        category_index,
        instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8)
    # plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
    # plt.imshow(image_np)

    cv2.imshow('image', image_np)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: convert to RGB before displaying. Use `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` before displaying.
`

Comment: you can otherwise use numpy indexing: `img = img[..., ::-1]` before displaying.

Comment: Thank you the answers ^^. I got my correct colour by change this code. 

Change-----> cv2.imshow('image', image_np) ----- To -----> cv2.imshow('image', cv2.cvtColor(image_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opencv uses BGR and Matplotlib RGB. You have to:
    `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`